# Numpy reduce 3d array to 2d based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d array like this:

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0],
        [ 6,  7]]])
```

What I am trying to do is reduce it to a 2d array like this:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Where there is a 1 for each sub-array of the original that had non-zero elements, and a 0 if all the elements of the corresponding sub-array were zero.

How can I do this cleanly, without loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ndarray.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html#numpy.ndarray.any) along the last axis (`axis=-1`):

```
>>> arr = np.array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0],
        [ 6,  7]]])

>>> arr.any(axis=-1).astype(int)
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```